# understading Windows8 roaming and local data storage

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, data-storage

I want to make an application in windows 8 metro style. THis will be my first application. learning the concepts of Windows-8. I want to make a simple application where user can store some note. I want the applicaiton to use roaming data storage so that the notes are available over the cloud and on other devices of the user. But according to msdn http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/Hh464917 roaming data is only available for 30 days(if app is not accesed), and local storage data cannot be accessed on other devices.
My question is if I use roaming data storage and for some reason user dnt open the app for 30 days(though very unlikely but just in case), all his notes will be gone from all devices, right? if thats the case what should I use to prevent this situation. Can I save data to both storage types?

**Thanks**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that cases, an Azure backend is recomended, Mobile Services to be exact. Those are free, as far as I know (with usage limitations).

And yes, you can store the notes in both storages, then check if the note is stored in the Roaming Data, if it's not, restore it from local storage.

Comment: I have completely no idea about Azure, will definitely look into it. Thanks.

Comment: [Windows Azure Mobile Services](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/) is in preview and free, with the expectation of a free tier to continue; however, the data storage is Windows Azure SQL Database which has a monthly cost varying with size of the database.